# MySQL: how to get the last record?

Tags: mysql, sql

Say I have the following records:

```
1, A
1, B
2, A
2, B
2, C
1, C
```

I want the last record for `1` and `2`, which should be `1, C` and `2, C`. How do I query that?

If I do a GROUP BY on the number, I get `1, A` and `2, A`.

Comment: SQL has no concept of "last", at least not in a chronological sense.  You would need to add some autoincrementing field to be able to identify the "last" record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that we've established that you mean "last" as in "chronologically", then I can create a proper answer...

SQL has no concept of chronology.  So you will have to record the insertion order yourself.  Most typically, you would add an autoincrementing field, and then use that in an `ORDER BY` clause, along with a `LIMIT` clause.

Answer (score 3):

if by 'last' you mean maximum alphabetically, then maybe this:

```
select id, max(val)
from mytable
group by id
```

Comment: Not alphabetically. I really do mean last record. My sample is just to simplify the problem.

Comment: @StackOverflowNewbie: The data only really has an order if you sort it, e.g., you can ask for the last row in a table that has a timestamp column.

Answer (score 1):

Without some sort of index or insertion order, there's no way of getting what you want; SQL queries are order non-deterministic.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not alphabetic, then you need to use LIMIT and so just do the following.

```
select @rownum:=@rownum+1 as naturalorder, * from foo, (SELECT @rownum:=0) nat order by naturalorder desc limit 1;
```

but warning that there is no guarantee from mysql on the order of the records. so you might want to add an extra field with a timestamp fields or an auto_increment which will have the order that you are looking for, i think.

If it is alphabetical, the trick is to order by the code descending and then get the 1st record. And you can limit that by one.

```
select num, code from thetable order by code DESC limit 1
```

if you use group by, you have to scan through the entire table. and also it's difficult to get the full record.

Comment: There is no guaranteed order of the table, so that first query could give you anything.  You might as well remove it from your answer, because it's not going to work!

Comment: natural order can change and i said that but he might have a reason for wanting it so i put it in there.